# Python script works in vscode but not rstudio

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, rstudio, reticulate

We have some python code that takes an excel file as input and processes it into a json file for some javascript to visualize.  To complicate this further, the javascript (and a bunch of other code) is rendered via an rmarkdown.  What's really weird though is that when I try to either source the whole script or use the functions in the python script with `source_python` or run the file directly in rstudio, the json file fails to populate properly; but it works just fine when I run the script in vscode.  I really want to get this to work in rmarkdown/rstudio so that this json file is produced automatically; now I have to run this manually in jscode before I can knit the rmarkdown.

Now I could just rewrite this in R, but as I imagine this problem will come up in the future I would love to figure it out.

So I read in the excel file as a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

pd.DataFrame(data={'Supplier': {412: 'QUEST DIAGNOSTICS', 317: 'MCKESSON', 207: 'GE HEALTHCARE', 570: 'QUEST DIAGNOSTICS ', 495: 'SANDIA NATIONAL LABORATORIES'}, 
 'Title': {412: 'Quest Diagnostics data breach: Nearly 12 million patients had ...', 317: "McKesson subsidiary exposed over 10,000 patients' information via ...", 207: 'Cyber vulnerability discovered in GE Healthcare radiological ...', 570: "Ransomware attack on Quest's ReproSource impacts data of 350K ...", 495: "US nuclear weapons agency target of major cyberattack;A governmentofficial has described it as the 'worsthacking case in the history of America. They got into everything'"}, 
 'Date': {412: Timestamp('2021-05-27 00:00:00'), 317: Timestamp('2021-05-27 00:00:00'), 207: Timestamp('2021-05-27 00:00:00'), 570: Timestamp('2021-10-12 00:00:00'), 495: Timestamp('2020-12-18 00:00:00')}, 
 'Source': {412: '202illuminate', 317: '202illuminate', 207: '202illuminate', 570: '202illuminate', 495: 'The Independent (United Kingdom)'}, 
 'Schema Category': {412: 'Cyber', 317: 'Cyber', 207: 'Cyber', 570: 'Cyber', 495: 'Cyber'}, 
 'Rubric Score': {412: 'Medium', 317: 'High', 207: 'Medium', 570: 'Medium', 495: 'Medium'},
'Relevant Information': {412: 'Data for nearly 12 million Quest Diagnostics patients may have been exposed', 317: "McKesson subsidiary exposed over 10,000 patients' information via ...", 207: 'Cyber vulnerability discovered in GE Healthcare radiological ...', 570: 'Oct 12, 2021 ... Approximately 350,000 patients were recently notified that their data was potentially accessed or acquired during a ransomware attack on ReproSource Fertility Diagnostics, a clinical laboratory for fertility specialists and a subsidiary of Quest Diagnostics.', 495: 'Networks hacked as part of the widespread cyberespionage attack on a number of federal agencies.'}, 
 'Test Supplier': {412: 'Test Supplier', 317: 'Test Supplier', 207: 'Test Supplier', 570: 'Test Supplier', 495: 'Test Supplier'}
}
```

I then create the structure of my eventual json file that looks like this:

```
[{'group': 'Test Supplier', 
  'data': [{'label': 'Cyber', 'data': []}, 
           {'label': 'Financial', 'data': []}, 
           {'label': 'Foreign Influence', 'data': []}, 
           {'label': 'Governance', 'data': []}, 
           {'label': 'Legal/Regulatory', 'data': []}, 
           {'label': 'Operational', 'data': []}, 
           {'label': 'Other', 'data': []}, 
           {'label': 'Production', 'data': []}]
}]
```

And I want to populate that json file using this function:

```
def populate_structure(row):
    """help each record find its home"""
    global structure

    entry = {}

    start = int(row['Date'].timestamp())*1000
    stop = int((row['Date'] + datetime.timedelta(days=15)).timestamp())*1000
    
    entry['timeRange'] = [start, stop]
    entry['val'] = row['Rubric Score']
    entry['name'] = row['Supplier']
    entry['desc'] = row['Title']

# ewww...
    group_index = structure.index([group for group in structure if group['group'] == row['Test Supplier']][0])
    label_index = structure[group_index]['data'].index([label for label in structure[group_index]['data'] if label['label'] == row['Schema Category']][0])

    structure[group_index]['data'][label_index]['data'].append(entry)    

    return None
```

Like this:

```
df = pre_process()
structure = build_structure(df)
df.apply(populate_structure,axis=1)
```

Function works just like it should in vscode, but doesn't seem to do anything in rstudio/r.  Any thoughts here?

Results of `session_info()`:

```
- Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2021-11-24                  

- Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 bit           4.0.4   2020-08-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 bit64         4.0.5   2020-08-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 blob          1.2.1   2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 cli           2.3.0   2021-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 DBI           1.1.1   2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 digest        0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 hms           1.0.0   2021-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 htmltools     0.5.1.1 2021-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 jsonlite      1.7.2   2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 knitr         1.31    2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 lattice       0.20-41 2020-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 lifecycle     1.0.0   2021-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 magrittr      2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 Matrix        1.3-2   2021-01-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 openxlsx      4.2.3   2020-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 png           0.1-7   2013-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 Rcpp          1.0.6   2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 reticulate    1.20    2021-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 rlang         0.4.11  2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 rmarkdown     2.7     2021-02-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 RPostgres     1.3.1   2021-01-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 stringi       1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 vctrs         0.3.8   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 withr         2.4.2   2021-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 xfun          0.22    2021-03-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
 zip           2.1.1   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)

[1] C:/Users/benja/Documents/R/win-library/3.6
[2] C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library
```

Comment: So what have you tried in R ?

Comment: I would prefer not to rewrite it in R

Comment: what I meant is that you are tagging r and reticulate but only show python code... so you are sourcing the python files in R with reticulate and its not working ? would be good to see some code for that...

Comment: Sure, but the R is basically just `source_python("script.py")`

Comment: Can you run `session_info(info = "all")` and post the results?

Comment: What do you expect as an output or side effect of running `script.py`? If it's printing, it should be explicit in the Python code. And what is your method of running Python in VSCode (there can be a number of ways)

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when you run it in RStudio? Can you verify you are using the same virtual environment or conda environment in both VSCode and RStudio?

Comment: No error messages.  I'm expecting `structure` to be populated based on the input dataframe

Comment: Just a hunch ... but write this in python without the global and try again.

Comment: Nope, that's not it

Comment: @Roman, added session info